# How to handle errors with sidebase/nuxt-auth?

Tags: error-handling, nuxt.js, nuxt3, nuxt-auth

I'm trying to use `sidebase/nuxt-auth` with my own backend (also in Nuxt, same app) for authentication. I couldn't find any example or in the docs about errors handling when the library is doing the requests (not triggered manually).
If `refresh` endpoint, used to refresh token, returns an error, it is not being handled. Ideally it should logout.
Is there a way to add a handler in that scenario?

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand your question.
Maybe this https://sidebase.io/nuxt-auth/resources/errors or maybe you are looking to implement a protected event handler ( https://sidebase.io/nuxt-auth/server-side/session-access-and-route-protection & https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-utilities )

If you mean hooking in to any event if this error is triggered, i'm not sure where i can find any either, maybe this is a good place to start: https://sidebase.io/nuxt-auth/configuration/nuxt-auth-handler & https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#callbacks .

Answer (score 0):

as you can see at this issue [conversation](https://github.com/sidebase/nuxt-auth/issues/583#issuecomment-1844963724)

they do not return http response.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).